# How can I convert a Custom Taxonomy to a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've not been able to find any information on this - a bit of an unusual request.

I've decided I'm best off creating a Custom Post Type to handle my database of Artists and Albums on my music site, currently stored as a Custom Taxonomy. There's clearly more flexibility in CPTs than Taxonomies. I'm going to use [Scribu's Posts2Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to connect my current CPTs (Videos, Lyrics, Reviews etc) with the Artists and Albums CPTs.

Since I have a large-ish quantity in my Artists Taxonomy including lots of meta data, I'm looking for a way to carry the data to a CPT (and corresponding Meta Fields) - too much to do by hand.

Has anyone else got this issue, and has anyone got a solution?

**UPDATE**:
I'm writing a function that I hope will achieve what I need. I'm a bit stuck however.

```
function make_posts_from_taxonomy($taxonomy, $post_type) {
// Get all Taxonomy
$args = array(
'parent' => 0
);

$taxonomy = 'hhie_artists';
$post_type = 'hhie_artists';

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $id = $term->ID;
    $name = $term->name; //Title
    $slug = $term->slug; //Slug
    $description = $term->description; //Description

$new_post = array(  
        'post_title' => $name,
        'post_content' => $description,
        'post_name' => $slug,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
    );
    //Insert post
    wp_insert_post ($new_post);

    } //End foreach

} //End function
```

This has worked. I've been able to create the new CPT posts.
Remaining issues:

1. I can't work out how to call all the metadata associated with each `$term`.
2. How can I then pass each piece of metadata into each post?

Comment: How taxonomy metadata are stored?

Comment: As is shown <a href="http://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/">here</a>, but I have several metadata fields using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this myself using a fairly basic (and pretty hacky) solution in the form of a plugin. It is shared as a Gist if anyone runs into the same issue as me: https://gist.github.com/Strap1/8053824